# Mysql Access Denied error after server crash

Tags: mysql

Our Server crashed with a power failure. After restarting, we are not able to log in to mysql.

mysql -uxxxx -pxxx gives the error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

We ran namp localhost nad the output was

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
22/tcp    open  ssh
23/tcp    open  telnet
80/tcp    open  http
443/tcp   open  https
3306/tcp  open  mysql
```

Gave service mysqld restart and got this error.

```
Stopping MySQL:                                            [  OK  ]
Initializing MySQL database:                               [  OK  ]
Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon.
Starting MySQL:        [FAILED]
```

mysqld log file has this:

```
130309 11:56:10  mysqld started
/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '4.1.7'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

and there is enough space in harddisk.

i am sure we are giving the correct password. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Using quotes around your password?

Comment: No. Mysql -uxxx -pxxx

Comment: No. Even with quotes the same error. But are quotes needed?

Comment: If you have any special characters in your password you should wrap the command in single quotes:  '-p passwordhere'

Comment: OK. thanks for the info. Was not aware of that. BUt no special characters here.

Answer (score 0):

Run these :

```
$ service mysqld stop; mysqld_safe &
```

Then read these. Post your findings

```
# tail -n 60 /var/log/messages
# tail -n 60 /var/log/mysqld.log
# tail -n 60 /var/lib/mysql/*.err
# tail -n 60 /var/log/mysql/error.log
```